# jQuery gmap3 syntax error

Tags: jquery, syntax, google-maps-api-3, jquery-gmap3

Im working with the jQuery plugin gmap3. I can get multiple markers to be added to a map but ive got stuck trying to give one of them an info window.

If I remove the code under the comment '//add a marker with info window' markers are created but without info windows. With the code how it is no map is created.

```
$('#test').gmap3(
  //create the map
  { action:'init'
  },

  //add a marker with info window
  { action: 'addInfoWindow',
    address: "London"
  },
  infowindow:{
    options:{
    content: 'This is London'
    },
    apply:[
        { action:'setContent',
            args:[
            '<span style="color:#000">Here is a new content !<span>'
            ]
        }   
    ]
    },

  //add a marker
  { action: 'addMarker',
    address: "Paris",
  },

  //add a marker
  { action: 'addMarker',
    address: "Madrid",
  }

  //autofit the map view
  ,
  "autofit"     

);
```

Im assuming this is a syntax issue, but ive got completely stuck so would really appreciate any help. Thanks

UPDATE Ive got it working with the following except the autofit feature doesnt work.

```
$('#test').gmap3({
  action: 'addMarker',
  address: "place de l'étoile, Paris",

  marker:{
    options:{
      draggable: false
    }
  },
  infowindow:{
    options:{
      content: 'Hello World !'
    },
    events:{
      closeclick: function(){
        alert("closing : " + $(this).attr("id")); 
      }
    }
  }
},

  //add a marker
  { action: 'addMarker',
    address: "London",
  },
      "autofit" 

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the workflow of gmap3 is very confusing, so it's easy to create some syntax-errors ^^

---

### Edit:

However, they better should flag this library as "beta" until they didn't fix some major issues(e.g. the autofit, that also didn't work in their own demo).

The major problem of "autofitting" with multiple markers is, that you must wait until all markers have been applied to the map.

So instead of repeated calls of `addMarker` use `addMarkers` and apply the "autofitting" in the callback of `addMarkers`.

As the autofit-option didn't work as expected, use the possibilities provided by the google-API:
create a **LatLngBounds**-object from the positions of the markers and apply the bounds using `map.fitBounds()`.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/BQyXb/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/BQyXb/)

Comment: Works except like my solution the autofit is ignored

Comment: Your solution didn't work , or am I missing something?  I removed the autofit, it throw's an exception when provided as last argument. Moved it now to infoWindow, there seems to be working.

Comment: What I meant was both our solutions work except that both dont use the autofit feature. Rather than the zoom being the whole map, with autofit the map should zoom in as much as it can while still containing all the markers. Thanks

Comment: My solution has the autofit applied now, and it works.(I've edited it)

Comment: Completely modified my answer and added demo.

Comment: I can see that your demo works but when I put the code into my document no map is created.

Comment: So you made something wrong. Did you recognize that I choose the onload-option for the fiddle?

Comment: Ive marked your answer as correct as it must be. However I still can't get it to work in my demo. My code opens with $(window).load(function () { is this correct? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Did you get any errors? Are you sure that the element is visible(I set the height of the map in the demo, otherwise you wouldn't see the map)

Comment: Yes, ive set a size for the map div. My console is saying 'script.js:31Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL' and its referring to the last line of your code with );

Answer (score 1):

you've got a trailing commas in your json

ie at address: London (2nd line under the comment you mention)

When it's the last item of a javascript object do not supply a comma

Also, infoWindow looks inappropriately placed. it should be placed in curly braces I would guess that it likely belongs at the end of the function call, but I'm unfamiliar with the Gmap3 api.

Looking at the API it looks like there's cleaner ways to declare all of this. I would refer to http://gmap3.net/api.html

It looks like infoWindow belongs in the action: "infoWindow" object

something like:

```
$('#test').gmap3(
  //create the map
  { 
    action:'init'
  },

  //add a marker with info window
  { 
    action: 'addInfoWindow',
    address: "London"
    infowindow:{
      options:{
        content: 'This is London'
      },
      apply:[
          { action:'setContent',
              args:[
              '<span style="color:#000">Here is a new content !<span>'
              ]
          }   
        ]
      }
  },

  //add a marker
  { 
    action: 'addMarker',
    address: "Paris"
  },

  //add a marker
  { 
    action: 'addMarker',
    address: "Madrid"
  }

  //autofit the map view
  ,
  "autofit"     

);
```

Comment: Ive removed the comma but it still doenst work. Ive updated by question. Thanks

Comment: I think I found the issue for you. infoWindow belongs in the action object.

Comment: Still getting a blank screen im afraid.

Comment: @danpickett: there is a comma missing after `address: "London"` .Also the marker is missing for London.

Comment: With the comma added the code works except for the info window missing a marker. Almost there! Thanks